# Salesforce endpoint not retrieving all data of the data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I am using the undocumented endpoint:  `"https://{subdomain}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/data/v1/customobjectdata/key/{data_extension_id}/rowset"` to extract data from my data extensions on Salesforce Marketing Cloud. When filtering by dates, like:
`"https://{subdomain}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/data/v1/customobjectdata/key/{landind}/rowset?$filter={date_column_encoded}%20between%20'{initial_date}T00:00:00'%20and%20'{end_date}T00:00:00'"` 
everything works well.

However, I wanted to use the same endpoint (the first I posted here) in order to download all the data from the data extension. When I run it without dates filtering, I only get always 2500 rows, independently of the number of rows of the data extension on Salesforce. Can someone help me? Is there any limit on the endpoint response?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can check documentation here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/references/mc-custom_object_data?meta=Get%2Bcustom%2Bobject%2Bdata%2Bby%2Bkey